# Fail With JavaCV not Responding RTSP in frameGrabber.start()

Tags: java, rtsp, javacv

I have one program to get one video in protocol rtsp using JavaCV:

My program is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    FrameGrabber frameGrabber = new 

    FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtsp://ip:port/login&password");

    CanvasFrame canvasFrame = new CanvasFrame("Test");

    frameGrabber.start();

    for(int i = 0; i<frameGrabber.getLengthInFrames(); i++){
       canvasFrame.showImage(frameGrabber.grab());
    }
    frameGrabber.flush();

    canvasFrame.dispose();
}
```

If I use one correct link rtsp my program return and I can deal with he.

But if the link are incorrect or the ipcam are desconnected the program not return in the command **frameGrabber.start();**

The program crash, not return error and not do more nothing.

I've already tried use try catch but didn't have sucess, the program not return.

**Edit**:

I did tests with other protocols like http, and it does not occur this problem, the program return one message that can not open the link, to http are ok, but when using rtsp not return.

Comment: my bad, the correct protocol and tag is rtsp thanks.

Comment: I did tests with other protocols like http, and it does not occur this problem, the program return one message that can not open the link, to http are ok, but when using rtsp not return.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.

It is necessary you define one timeout.

streamGrabber.setOption("timeout" , "3");

The default value for this parameter is '-1' (infinite).

"Timeout
Set maximum timeout (in seconds) to wait for incoming connections.

A value of -1 means infinite (default). This option implies the rtsp_flags set to ‘listen’."